# How do I create an ARM Templates of an app function?

Tags: azure-rm-template

I am creating ARM template of job of Stream Analytics but it fails. It gives me the next error message:

> {"code":"ExportTemplateCompletedWithErrors","message":"La operación de
>   exportación de plantillas se ha completado con errores y algunos de
>   los recursos no se han exportado. Consulte los detalles para obtener
>   más información al
>   respecto.","details":[{"code":"ExportTemplateProviderError","target":"Microsoft.Web/sites/functions","message":"No
>   se pueden obtener los recursos del tipo
>   'Microsoft.Web/sites/functions'. Los recursos de dicho tipo no se
>   exportarán."}]}

Comment: 2 things, translate the error into english and give us your template

Comment: I am trying to generate a template (ARM) from the Azure portal of an app function with the option "Export template" but although it generates the JSON, it also get get the error message.

Comment: This is the traslation of the error message:

Comment: {"code": "ExportTemplateCompletedWithErrors", "message": "The template export operation has completed with errors and some of the resources have not been exported. See details for more information.", "details" : [{"code": "ExportTemplateProviderError", "target": "Microsoft.Web / sites / functions", "message": "Cannot obtain resources of type 'Microsoft.Web / sites / functions'. Resources of that type will not be exported. "}]}

Answer (score 0):

Well, in this case nothing you can really do about this. [Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-infrastructure-as-code) the official doc on how to deploy function apps. Technically [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/createfunction) is how to create a function - so this is what you need to replicate in the template